# Does Crashlytics need ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE?

Tags: android, crashlytics

I received this log via Crashlytics:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10099 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1428)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1382)
   at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:737)
   at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:566)
   at android.webkit.TextSelectWindow.isNetworkAvailable(TextSelectWindow.java:903)
   at android.webkit.TextSelectWindow.dictSelection(TextSelectWindow.java:475)
   at android.webkit.TextSelectWindow.onClick(TextSelectWindow.java:365)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4220)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17510)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:966)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:733)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Apparently, something requires the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission. The only permission the app currently has is INTERNET, which I only need to receive crash logs via Crashlytics. The app itself never needs any Internet connection and works perfectly without having any permissions whatsoever. Now does that mean Crashlytics requires ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE to work correctly? The strange thing is that this is the first and single crash after a whole crash-free month and Crashlytics always worked without the permission.

The app targets SDK 21 and uses crashlytics:1.1.13 and crashlytics-gradle:1.14.7.

Comment: You mentioned you got this through a crashlytics log, so it was not from your own device? Its looking like it went into the webkit and the TextSelectWindow class tried to access the network state by checking connectivity. I ask if it was your phone because I don't see TextSelectWindow in the webkit anywhere. Maybe someone running a modified version of android on a rooted device? https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/webkit

Comment: @DejanRistic That's correct, not my device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crashlytics only needs INTERNET permissions. The ConnectivityManager needs the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission

Comment: I thought so, but what might be using the ConnectivityManager when I'm not accessing anything over the Internet? I'm only using WebViews to show local HTML content like this: *webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName(HTTP.UTF_8);
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + name + ".html");* Even though this single crash is very negligible, I still think it's really odd that an Android app can crash from not having ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE when it's 100% offline.

Comment: I believe ConnectivityManger's getActiveNetworkInfo and isNetworkAvailable methods require that permissions. I saw those being called in your crash log.

Comment: And Android might call those for fun from any app? I'm never doing anything networkish, nor am I using any library for that. The only libraries I'm using are Crashlytics and Daimajia's Android View Animations.

Comment: @0101100101: This error has nothing to do with Crashlytics. You are finding out about the error through Crashlytics. I use ACRA and a different backend service, and I have gotten a pair of crashes with the same stack trace as yours. In my case, Huwaei appears to have modified `WebView` such that it requires `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`, at least on one device.